# Need help coding a downloader for Dropbox

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am writing a C# application that downloads from a shared Dropbox folder using Dropbox API. I am able to access my own account and folders and files. But when I try to access the given link which looks like this:

https://wixlabs---dropbox-folder.appspot.com/index?instance=UexTyTTXTALjKbz1f1P3H5nZAFTiMsLw2wWcu_0uebU.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiNzk4YzZlYTUtMDg5Yi00ZjFlLWI2NzMtOWYxZjA1OTU1YmQ5IiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxNDkyNDg2NC01NmQ1LWI5NGItMDYwZi1jZDU3YmQxNmNjMjYiLCJtZXRhU2l0ZUlkIjoiYmRkMzFlNjMtY2I5Ny00ZTMxLWI5NGEtMGFhNmI5MzgwYjY3Iiwic2lnbkRhdGUiOiIyMDE4LTEwLTA0VDAwOjE4OjIyLjM5MFoiLCJ1aWQiOm51bGwsInZlbmRvclByb2R1Y3RJZCI6bnVsbCwiZGVtb01vZGUiOmZhbHNlfQ&target=_top&width=576&compId=comp-jmtmo1bb&viewMode=viewer-seo

I get an exception that the path could not be found, but the path exists as I have used the link in the browser to download the files. So, I suspect that it has something to do with the link itself that I keep getting this error. 
I have used the following code to read the folder:

```
private async static Task RunOnPublicUrlAsync(string url)
{
            using (var dbx = new DropboxClient("My Access code Here"))
            {
                var metadata = await dbx.Sharing.GetSharedLinkMetadataAsync(url);
                Console.WriteLine($"{metadata.IsFolder}, {metadata.Name}");
            }
}
```

I pass the above url to the method above but I get `shared_link_not_found/...`
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Developer-API/How-to-use-the-public-url-to-access-files/m-p/328617 ]

Comment: @Greg Thanks for cross referencing the post!